# jQuery load function not working but no error

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, load

I am new to jQuery and I cannot figure out why this snippet of code does not work, even though it is similar to many of the ones I've found online.

I have two files, `index.php` and `masterPage.php`. I want to include a `<div>` from `masterPage.php` called `my_table` into `index.php`. The thing is that, even if I cannot see the results, I do not catch any error either. Any ideas? It must be something really basic I am missing here.

Here is my code for `index.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <script src="jquery/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $( "#something" ).load( "./masterPage.php #my_table", {limit: 25}, 
          function (responseText, textStatus, req) {
           if (textStatus == "error") {
             return "oh noes!!!!";
           }
          });
      });
     </script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="something"> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can not do this like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote **class** name for **div** and accessing like id element(**#something**) from jquery. Because of that jquery not producing any error. jQuery is checking for **something** which was wrote as id in document.

Change

`<div class="something">` to `<div id="something">`

Then it will produce result if the url called otherwise it gives error.

Comment: Oh God. You have no idea how much time I've spent trying to figure out what was wrong...and the mistake was just so silly. Thanks!